# Why can't I build Stone pavement?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Just below my base there are some tiles where I cannot build Stone Cubes, that would establish a stone basement for it. But I can place Stone Cubes on other tiles nearby.

Am I doing some kind of mistake? Which one?

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm reading that UI wrong, it says you have 12 small stone and need 25?

Comment: @TimmyJim Thank you, but it's not related to this. The game allows me to place the frame of the Stone Cube if I have at least 1 Stick, and build it later when I gather the other materials. And I could place the Stone Cube on the tile immediately to the right.

Comment: Reported on their Bugtracker: https://communityedition.medievalengineers.com/mantis/view.php?id=399